# Programmer's Dvorak in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am a user of [Programmer's Dvorak](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/) and had it installed on windows 8.1. I recently upgraded to Windows 10 and am unable to use the instructions on the site to install programmer's dvorak.

I install it (the installation runs) but it does not show up in the kepboards section afterwards.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 8):

I just took the layout and created it using the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=22339) and following the instructions at [littletinyfish](http://littletinyfish.com/create-a-new-keyboard-layout-with-the-microsoft-keyboard-layout-creator/).

1. Go to File > Load Existing Keyboard…
2. Choose the keyboard you like. If you want to keep QWERTY, but add additional characters, you’ll want to load they keyboard called “US.”
3. select File > Save Source File As… and save
   it wherever you want to save your keyboards.
4. go to Project > Properties

   - Name can only be 8 characters
   - Description is the name of the keyboard you will see most often
   - Choose the language that makes the most sense.
   - Click okay.

Then I configured the layout as described on the Programmer's Dvorak site:

[image: Programmer's Dvorak Layout]

Once done:

1. Project > Validate Layout
2. Project > Test Keyboard Layout
3. Project > Build DLL and Setup Package
4. Optionally, you can File > Save As Image… to print out as a reminder.
5. It should ask you if you want to open the directory. If not, you have to navigate to where you initially saved your keyboard. You’ll find a folder with the Title of the keyboard (the 8 character title you selected earlier).
6. Click Setup.exe and follow the instructions. It’ll tell you your keyboard was installed successfully, but you won’t be able to use it until you restart.
7. Restart the machine.
8. Once the machine is restarted, you should be good to go.

On Windows 8 (and 10), you just have to hit WinKey + Space to switch between the two or more keyboard layouts.

I installed the resulting keyboard from the settings app and it works as expected.

Comment: see also: https://github.com/jayliu50/windows-programmer-dvorak

Answer (score 2):

One thing not mentioned by [Siamore's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1036982/86708) is how to get CAPS LOCK behavior to match Programmer Dvorak (e.g. for underscore and numbers) when using Keyboard Layout Creator. Here's how:

1. First, open the edit dialog for a key by clicking on it. In this case, I chose <kbd>[</kbd> to edit.

   [image: The edit dialog, with All as the third and last button]
2. Click *All*. to see all of the characters assigned to that key. Check *caps = shift*, so that CAPS LOCK will affect that key, in addition to all of the letter keys. Press *OK*.

   [image: The expanded edit dialog, showing all of the shift states. The caps-equals-shift checkbox precedes the second text input box]
3. Preview the results by selecting *Show the Caps Lock*. Note that this view does not automatically refresh when you make changes, so you'll have to toggle it if it has already been selected.

   [image: After clicking the Show-the-Caps-Lock button, the keyboard layout preview updated to display the changes made]

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a tool called [Power Toys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) which supports key mapping.

1. Install [Power Toys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/)
2. Run it
3. Select "Keyboard Manager" on the nav bar on the left
4. Click "Remap a Key"

You'll get to a screen that is straight-forward to use. I could add screenshots but I'm sure the UI will change slightly over time. There is currently an accurate screenshot [here](https://zachrussell.net/blog/map-caps-lock-to-control-windows#powertoys)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).