# How can I use UK DVORAK Layout on Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, dvorak

How can I use UK DVORAK Layout on Windows 10 Pro?

Note **UK**! I can install a US one fine from the control panel. However Windows 10 does **not** come with a UK DVORAK one.

Microsoft provides [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboardlayouts.aspx), but it doesn't seem to have been updated for Windows 10. And if you try and run it, it asks for .Net Framework version 2 which also hasn't been updated for Windows 10.

Comment: Besides attempting to use a tool designed to work with Windows 7 and earlier, have you tried adding an dvorak keyboard layout within Windows 10?  Should be offered witin the Settings application.

Comment: Related: [Programmer's Dvorak in Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/1036981/programmers-dvorak-in-windows-10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get DVORAK keyboard layout on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/548441/how-do-i-get-dvorak-keyboard-layout-on-windows).  My rational for this being a duplicate, it explains how to get the Dvorak layout using your current regional keyboard layout.  If a UK Dvorak layout exists this would be how you enable it.  If it does not exist, use the solution, described in the related link and create it manually.

Comment: @Ramhound Note the UK in the title. I can get a US one working fine via the normal control panel.

Comment: If it exists for US keyboard layout I see no reason it wouldn't exist for the UK layout also.  If you could provide screenshots, which sort of indicate that the Dvorak option is missing from the general (English?) UK layout that would be great.  Which of course is the reason in my original comment i indicate, if it doesn't exist, you would have to create it using the approach in the first possible duplicate.  The regional setting of the system shouldn't prevent Dvorak (R) or Dvorak (L) from being selected.

Comment: Are you talking about this layout: http://www.tarind.com/ukdvorak.html

Comment: @music2myear Yes. A £ is put on the 3 key, which makes sense. And a few others are swaped, not sure why.

Comment: I have mine created with autohotkey which I prefer it that way for a bunch of reasons

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to get it working? Microsoft seems to have released an updated version of the keyboard layout creator tool which works with windows 10.

For anyone else finding this, the steps are:

(1) download and install the keyboard creator tool

(2) download the keyboard layout file from here http://www.tarind.com/ukdvorak.html

(3) load that layout file in the keyboard creator

(4) click tools and then create dll

(5) find the folder with the dll file you created, and in there there will be a program called setup.exe - run that file to install the keyboard

(6) select the new keyboard using the keyboard layout control panel program (it will be called 'unknown input method' but it should still work)

(7) ask microsoft why this is so difficult when this layout has been included in other operating systems for more than 20 years!

Comment: I did get a answer to my problem, by using the procedure in my own answer. It's been down-voted for some reason so it may be semi-hidden for you or something. But it's good to hear MS has finally updated this - thanks for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

Go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=6523 - Microsoft .NET Framework Version 2.0 Redistributable Package (x64)

Download and Run - Windows 10 asks: An App on your PC needs the following Windows feature: .NET Framework 3.5 (Includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)

Install this.

Now you can install and use the Keyboard Programme as detailed in [Programmer's Dvorak in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1036981/programmers-dvorak-in-windows-10)

Comment: Apparently the Keyboard Programme has been updated, so the step of installing the older .NET package shouldn't be needed any more. See @bigcroc's answer for more.